# Feature extraction from the text

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, feature-extraction

I am a newbie in machine learning but I have a coursework to create program that can extract some concrete features from the given text.

For example:
If I want to extract number of red apples and green apples, I will extract 3, 5 from "On that tree 3 red apples and 5 green apples grow" and 10, 1000 from "In the box there are 1000 green apples and 10 of red".
Actually the real examples can be more complicated like a extracting a car specification from the ad.

The concrete features are known before the data set processing.

Could you suggest what kind of algorithms I should use? Previously, I used only linear regression.

Comment: I guess neural networks would help you in this.
If you create a network which could distinguish between numbers and characters i guess it will help you. Split the sentence according to spaces ,pass each word to network for identification ,and if it is a no just extract it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you know what you want to extract you can just find it using **regular expressions** for integers or car specifications.

Comment: No, it does not work. The samples are in various formats and may contain typos.